# Duda advertencia en c#

Tags: c#

tenia una pregunta a ver si alguno me la puede resolver y es que empezado hace poco con la programacion y en mis clases el profesor del grado superior no le sale esta advertencia cuando programa y a mi si y no se el motivo estoy haciendo esto en Visual Studio 2022 en C#. Creo que no afecta al resultado pero me da curiosidad el saber porque de esa advertencia y si tiene solucion, gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ahí mismo está el código del mensaje del compilador. Te recomiendo encarecidamente hagas una costumbre primero buscar en la documentación oficial, y luego preguntar en otros foros. El código es [CS8600](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings). El compilador te está advirtiendo para que tomes medidas que eviten un `NullReferenceException`. En esta carrera, la investigación por tu cuenta es oro.

Comment: Tanto para las preguntas como para las respuestas, coloca código en texto por favor, gracias. :D

Answer (score 7):

Esta es una advertencia de Visual Studio que te indica que el valor devuelto puede ser nulo. Generalmente un valor nulo produce problemas de borde que deben atenderse, y esta advertencia es útil para el desarrollador para que tenga eso en cuenta. Es tanto así que esta advertencia la arroja incluso con string, cuando el string si acepta valores nulos.

Tienes 2 estrategias para controlar esta advertencia

**1.- Aceptar la posibilidad que sea nulo**

Con el ? convierties el string en nullable

```
string? teclado = Console.ReadLine();
```

Esta es una buena manera ya que cada vez que usas la variable `teclado`, te vuelve a advertir que puede haber un problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, que pasa si controlamos el problema??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LA advertencia desaparece, porque con el if ya estamos verificando que no sea nulo

**2.- Negar la posibilidad que sea nulo**

Hay caso donde sabemos que no será nulo nunca. Por ejemplo en Console.ReadLine() si la entrada es por teclado nunca será nulo (lo que pasa es Console.ReadLine() se puede utlizar para otros fines donde si puede serlo)

Cuando pasa esto, negamos que será nulo con un ! al final

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tanto para las preguntas como para las respuestas, coloca código en texto por favor, gracias. :D

Comment: @fredyfx En este caso no es posible. El fondo del asunto es ver el marcado que produce visual studio (el subrayado verde). Lo importante es hacer notar cuando aparece y cuando no

Comment: Sí es posible, se coloca el código y se hace referencia describiendo el comportamiento. Lo que pasa es que nada garantiza que el server donde se ha subido la imagen se vaya a quedar funcionando de por vida, tampoco hay garantías del 100% que link se mantenga. Gracias por comprender.

Comment: Debería de ser permitido porque está usando imgur que es lo que provee SO, si no fuese posible entonces no debería existir esa opción entonces.

Comment: Coloca ese reclamo/sugerencia de feature en meta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/ Saludos.

Comment: @fredyfx El reclamo/sugerencia lo debería hacer usted. Es usted el que quiere restringir las imágenes tanto en preguntas como en respuestas, aun cuando el sistema lo permite

Comment: Si deseas conversar, me encuentras aquí: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que `Console.ReadLine()` devuelve un tipo `string?`, el ? significa que dicho `string` puede tener valor `null`. El tipo de dato `string` sin ? no puede tener el valor `null`.

La solución para que no aparezca la advertencia sería:

```
string? teclado = Console.ReadLine();
```