# Cómo evitar correctamente nulls en propiedades de objetos

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

Estoy trabajando con un objeto con las siguientes características (aproximadamente) al que estoy tratando de mapear un objeto recibido desde una llamada API:

```
public class Company{

  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Zip { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public Billing Facturacion { get; set; }

}

public class Billing{

  public string FacturacionAnual { get; set; }
  public string FacturacionMensual { get; set; }

}
```

Existe la posibilidad de que el objeto o alguna de las características que lleguen den `Null`, por lo que actualmente lo valido de la siguiente forma.

```
var company = new Company();
var result = _myApi.GetCompany(id);

company.Id = result.InternalId;
company.Address = result != null ? result.address?.streetName : "" ; //Address puede ser NULL
company.Zip = result != null ? result.address?.ZIP : "" ; //Address puede ser NULL
{ ... }
```

El "problema" es que Visual Studio me llena este mapeo de ruido, indicando que alguna de las características, en este ejemplo, `result.address`, pueden ser `NULL`, por lo que entiendo que debe de haber alguna manera mejor, tanto para **mapear correctamente estos valores**, como para **evitar tener tantos mensajes de advertencia**.

El entorno de desarrollo es `Visual Studio 2022` y estoy trabajando con `.NET Core 6.0`.

---

Cabe destacar que ya he revisado la famosa "[Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%c3%a9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%c3%b3mo-solucionarla/76000#76000)", donde se referencia el problema exacto que tengo, pero la solución propuesta no me convence, debido a que la última edición de la respuesta es antigua y teniendo en cuenta la evolución de .NET Core desde 2017, considero apropiado ver si en este tiempo ha habido alguna característica nueva del lenguaje que permita resolver este problema de una forma un poco más elegante, simple y que genere la menor cantidad de ruido posible en el código.

Answer (score 3):

Vamos por partes.

**1) Sobre tus clases**

Tú puedes aceptar los valores nulos con el sufijo `?` o negarlos con `!`. Aquí hay una explicación sobre esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/566946/301324

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Company{
  public string? Id { get; set; } //aceptamos que puede ser nulo
  public string Name { get; set; } = default!; //una forma de eliminar la advertencia de VS
  public string Zip { get; set; } = null!; //otra forma de eliminar la advertencia
}
```

**2) Setear las propiedades**

Digamos que la propiedad Address no acepta nulos

```
public class Company{
  public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

*Nota: Un string si acepta nulos, por esto VS no arroja un error sino que una advertencia para que nos preocupemos de posibles casos de bordes que puedan ocurrir.*

La asignación queda así:

```
company.Address = result?.address?.streetName ?? string.Empty;
```

Esta expresion se divide en 2 partes:

```
result?.address?.streetName
```

- Si result es nulo, retorna nulo
- Si no es nulo evalua `address`
- Si `address` es nulo retorna nulo
- Si `address` no es nulo retorna `streetName`
- Luego `streetName` podría o no ser nulo, pero ya no es necesario hacer nada con eso

Es decir las propiedades hijas (o funciones, variables, etc) se evalúan siempre y cuando el objeto no sea nulo. Esta forma evita colocar repetidos `if` que era la forma antigua de validar

La segunda parte es el uso del operador `??` que hace lo siguiente:

- Si es nulo la parte de la izquierda, devuelve la parte de la derecha en este caso `string.Empty` pero podría ser lo que tu definas
- Si no es nulo, retorna la misma parte izquierda

---

Por otro lado, ahora supongamos que address si puede ser nulo

```
public class Company{
  public string? Address { get; set; }
}
```

En este caso la asignación queda así:

```
company.Address = result?.address?.streetName;
```

`result?.address?.streetName` podría ser nulo, pero esta vez address si lo soporta. (quedando una asignación mas corta)

---

En resumen, primero debes configurar bien las clases colocando `?` cuando sea necesario. De esta manera simplificas la asignación posterior de ellas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Yussef , ¿Qué indica la exclamación después de `default`? ¿Entiendo que en caso de `null!` prohíbe que pueda ser asignado como null por lo que en el caso de default, prohibe que sea default?

Comment: @Aritzbn No es así el sufijo ! SIEMPRE niega la posibilidad de que el valor sea NULO (se llama operador null-forgving). La situación rara se produce con null! ... un null que no será null?? esto es un cuento muy largo de explicar y de entender, pero digamos que es una notación especial, donde de esta manera le estoy prometiendo a VS que ese valor no será nulo y que me las arreglaré en tiempo de ejecución, esto por un carencia en C# con la inicialización de propiedades, que se resuelve en C# 11. Recuerda que si mi respuesta te pareció útil puedes marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Al usar el `!` estás indicando que nunca podrá ser null, eso es mejor usarlo cuánto haces una validación con un `if`, porque si es null tu aplicación te lanzara una excepción, pero en mi caso es mejor usar `?`